# Need to get data from Presto Teradata with restricting column data

Tags: sql, teradata

```
select * from rest where url like 'https://%.sureshchitturi.com:444/%/%';
```

i can get the data using above in where but i want something to use in select statement to get all data upto fourth '/' symbol rest not required suggest me some function to make it work

```
sample

Articles/Search/ArtMID/2681/ArticleID/2218/Diet.aspx
OurStory/boot/food/street/MeettheFoodieandtheMD.aspx
TheFood/OurMenu.aspx/abc/def/abbac

output

Articles/Search/ArtMID/2681
OurStory/boot/food/street
TheFood/OurMenu.aspx/abc/def
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If there are always at least four slashes you can use

```
Substr(col, 1, Instr(col, '/', 1, 4)-1)
```

Otherwise switch to a regex:

```
RegExp_Substr(col, '(.*?/){3}([^/]+)') -- at least .../.../.../.
```

Answer (score 0):

please execute below:

```
  SELECT RegExp_Substr('Articles/Search/ArtMID/2681/ArticleID/2218/Diet.aspx', '(.*?/){3}([^/]+)')  
    FROM dual;
```

Comment: There's no `dual` table in Teradata, otherwise it's an exact copy of my regex.